# A problem when using PageTransitionForward and Backward

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyssOSmwuoo

according to my video

when call animation PageTransitionForward it will have a triangle on the left
and that triangle can see through next layer

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of limitation of depth buffer (search about z-fighting for more info).

To fix it just find CCPageTurn3DAction.m file and in (void)update:(ccTime) method change z coordinate of all vertices of the animated grid to some higher value (e.g. 0.5).